# NameError: name 'reviews' is not defined

Tags: python

Facing error in this code please help.

```py
reviews['content'] = reviews['content'].map(lambda x: data_cleaning(x, slang_words))
print(reviews['content']
```

Comment: Hey @Isha Chouhan, could you attach more information about the code and the environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `reviews` as a dictionary before you use it.

`reviews = dict()
 reviews['content'] = reviews['content'].map(lambda x: data_cleaning(x, 
 slang_words)) print(reviews['content']`